# How to add alexa support for esp8266 with my brand configuration?

Tags: iot, alexa-skills-kit, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

I want a complete solution to develop my own Alexa skill and firmware for my IOT work on ESP8266. Over the internet i am seeing that we can emulate the device as Philips or Belkins (fauxmoesp). But i want to develop something for my own brand. Do i needs to talk to Alexa team for new development.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Alexa Connect Kit: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/alexa/connected-devices/alexa-connect-kit

With it you don't need to develop a skill at all, but rather concentrate on a firmware. Obviously you can have your own brand.

I'm not really into the details, my understanding that you need to purchase the USI Development Kit for Alexa Connect Kit on Amazon, once you have your prototype, you will need to contact Amazon.